# How can select all columns except some columns in SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

I have a lot of queries that join in a query, these queries join with one id column that this column repeat.

```
select t1.* , t2.* , t3.* , ...
from (query1) as t1 , (query2) as t2 , (query3) as t3 , ...
where t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id1 = t3.id3 and ...
```

Queries have many columns, I want to select all columns except some columns in each query.

For example :

```
select 
    t1.(all columns except some columns), 
    t2.(all columns except some columns),
    t3.* , ...
from 
    (query1) as t1 , (query2) as t2 , (query3) as t3 , ...
where
     t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id1 = t3.id3 and ...
```

how can I select all columns except some columns in sql 17?
thanks for advice.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, why are you choosing NOT to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a work around-

```
-- In step 1 insert your query output to a temp table
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM
(
   select t1.* , t2.* , t3.* , ...
   from (query1) as t1 , (query2) as t2 , (query3) as t3 , ...
   where t1.id1 = t2.id2 and t1.id1 = t3.id3 and ...
)

-- Then drop all columns from the temp table you wants to exclude 
-- from your final selection
ALTER TABLE #Temp
DROP COLUMN column_name1, column_name2

-- Finally, just select all records from temp table
SELECT * FROM #Temp
```